# Hibenate "Parameter value did not match expected type"

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, collections, orm

I want to insert a `List<Completed>` objects into a relational table, using Spring framework and Hibernate.

My entity class has the Collections List field -

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    ...
    
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Completed> completedList;

    ... // getters/setters
}
```

The data access repository -

```
public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {

    Optional<User> findByEmail(String email);

    @Modifying
    @Query(value = "update User set completedList = :completed where id = :id")
    @Transactional
    void addNewCompletion(@Param("completed") List<Completed> completed,
                          @Param("id") long userID);
}
```

I'm calling the method as such (for testing purposes) -

```
        Completed completed1 = new Completed(1, LocalDateTime.now());
        Completed completed2 = new Completed(2, LocalDateTime.now());
        Completed completed3 = new Completed(3, LocalDateTime.now());
        List<Completed> completedList = List.of(completed1, completed2, completed3);
//        completedList.add(completed1);
        UserService.updateUserCompletion(completedList, UserService.findUserID(currentUser));
```

I have also tried -

```
    List<Completed> completedList = new ArrayList()<>;
    completedList.add(new Completed()); // etc.
```

```
   Completed completed = new Completed(1, LocalDateTime.now());
   UserService.updateUserCompletion(completed, UserService.findUserID(currentUser));
```

Either which way results in the same exception -

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter value [io.github.siaust.web_quiz_app.Model.Completed@2f1eafc2] did not match expected type [java.util.Collection (n/a)]
```

I can't understand as I am passing a `List<Completed>` object to the `@Param` of the custom `@Query`? Why does the type not match?

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to update database relations like this. Collections is a specific type and giving a list of object in that way you give Hibernate no change to recognize this as a list and handle it correctly. When you use `@Query` hibernate simply runs your SQL code. That means Hibernate passes into your SQL code a collection as a param and database server could not resolve that collection  You also creating an immutable collection which is don't work here too. I think in your case this should work correctly:

```
User user = UserService.findUserID(currentUser);

List<Completed> completedList = new ArrayList<>();
completedList.add(new Completed(1, LocalDateTime.now()));
completedList.add(new Completed(2, LocalDateTime.now()));
completedList.add(new Completed(3, LocalDateTime.now()));


user.setCompleted(completedList);
userRepository.save(user);
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. I thought `List` extends `Collections`, so it would be acceptable type?
Are you saying I should create an object of the super type `Collections<Completed> collection = new ArrayList<>()`, would that be accepted?
I did try also to create a mutable `ArrayList<>()` and passed that as a param,  I left a commented out line to hint at that but should have made it clear. Still threw the exception.
So in this situation a relational database using a FK would not really be ideal, and it would be easier to just create/use a new table? Thanks.

Comment: Changing the type of collection to a more generic type won't fix that issue. The problem here is not about what collection type you use, but it's about using the collection at all. The mutability of collection is necessary here to give Hibernate an opportunity to change this collection and for all entities in this collection set the `user_id` property to id of the user entity which you created. I don't know what you mean "it would be easier to just create/use a new table" - please explain that. You have to create a new table if you wanna make a `@OneToMany` relation.